# Python Sharepoint API Authentication Successful But Can't Read Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

So basically the authentication to my sharepoint is successful, but then Pandas can't read the xlsx file (which is stored as a byte object).

I get the error:
"ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file"

Code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://**[company-name]**-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/**[email-prefix]**/EYSZCv_Su0tBkarOa5ggMfsB-5DAB-FY8a0-IKukCIaPOw?e=iW2K6r' # this is just the link you get when clicking "copy link" on sharepoint
username = '...'
password = '...'


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)
#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)
df
```

Any thoughts on to what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error (& arrived at this page).

I could solve this, changing the url link.
Using file path (got from 'copy path' on opened excel file), maybe it will work...

example:

```
url = 'https://**[company-name]**-my.sharepoint.com/personal/**[email-prefix]**/Documents/filename.xlsx?web=1'
```