# Getting BadZipFile error when trying to use python to read an excel file from SharePoint online

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sharepoint-online

I am trying to read a SharePoint excel file on python. I am using jupyter notebook. The authentication worked and it printed authentication successful. However, the part where I was trying to use pandas to read the file, I got an error saying BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Here is my code

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = 'the sharepoint excel file url'
username = 'my work email'
password = 'my password'
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username,password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url,ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()


    print('Authentication successful')

import io
import pandas as pd

bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)


df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj,engine='openpyxl')
print(df)'
```

I want to know how to fix this error or how to adjust my code to avoid this error. And I don't think I can zip the file on SharePoint. I am trying to read it directly from SharePoint, not to download it into my desktop first. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: where the heck did `response.content` come from, you didnt provide some key code here

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641888/python-sharepoint-api-authentication-successful-but-cant-read-excel-file) solution worked for me.

I had to grab the path to the file from excel by opening the file in desktop and copying the path under "info".

Then paste the path into your url variable:

url = 'path goes here'

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35694523)

Comment: The answer is simply opening the file in excel to get the path. I say that in my answer. I've added an edit in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Even with the additional text this is not really a programming answer.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I've mentioned that it should be used in the code in case that wasn't obvious...